# How to overcome a #import loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Imagine I have two header files: `SomeFileA.h` and `SomeFileB.h`

`SomeFileA.h` includes `SomeFileB.h`, and `SomeFileB.h` includes `SomeFileA.h`.

This creates a loop and confuse the compiler. How can we overcome this?

Comment: Forward declare in .h & import in .m !! And you are done.

Comment: If you are using `#import` then there shouldn't be an issue.  Are you getting an error  resulting from this "loop"?

Comment: @DanF #import get's loop import also, despite Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 8):

You should "forward declare" your classes. This tells the compiler that the class exists, but without the need to actually import it.

SomeFileA.h

```
@class SomeFileB  // <-- This "forward declares SomeFileB"
@interface SomeFileA

@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeFileB *someFileB;
...
@end
```

SomeFileA.m

```
#import "SomeFileB.h"
@implementation SomeFileA
...
@end
```

---

And the same thing, but the other way around in SomeFileB

SomeFileB.h

```
@class SomeFileA  // <-- This "forward declares SomeFileA"
@interface SomeFileB

@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeFileA *someFileA;
...
@end
```

SomeFileB.m

```
#import "SomeFileA.h"
@implementation SomeFileB
...
@end
```

---

**If you don't use a class in the header, you don't need to forward declare it.**

```
@interface SomeFileA
//I took out the property for SomeFileB.. no need for the @class anymore.
...
@end
```